# How to do batch insert using neo4j cypher and java

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I am performing single insert using for each loop for each value.

How can we do batch insert using cypher queries.

Here is my code...

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping("/geohash")
public Set<String>  create(@RequestParam String name, @RequestBody LatLng[] latLngs) {
    double[][] polygonPoints = convertTo2dArrayOfLatLng(latLngs);
    Set<String> geoHashesForPolygon = GeoHashUtils.geoHashesForPolygon(6, polygonPoints);
    for (String geohash : geoHashesForPolygon) {
        min = Math.min(min, geohash.length());
        geohashes = neoService.create(name, geohash);
    }
    return geoHashesForPolygon;
}
```

I want to insert each `geoHashesForPolygon` as single node..

**Cypher query**

```
@Query("MATCH (c:C) WHERE c.name = {name} CREATE (g: G{name : {geohash}} )<-[:cToG]-(c) RETURN c,g")
public GeohashOfCluster create(@Param("name") String name,@Param("geohash") String geohash);
```

Comment: Why not use code to create a CSV file and then use a LOAD CSV cypher query to bulk upload the file?

Comment: Hi, Cant we upload using java collections and cypher without CSV file...?

Comment: Note that Spring Data Neo4j isn't meant for high volume insertion. Highly recommend using LOAD CSV here.

Comment: @InverseFalcon Thank you for the response. Actually data is not of high volume. Suppose creating 10 nodes at a time, but with batch insertion. LOAD CSV is the only option in this case...?

Comment: @Hema Hey, any solutions for this scenario? I've face the same issue too since one rest API request will need to add thousands of nodes and relationships, which takes quite a long time to process. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: @KAs  Nope.. I used for each loop as it was less number of iterations. At tht time could'nt find any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the params in a list and unwind it to create nodes. Your query would be like `WITH [{name:'',geohash:''},{name:'',geohash:''},{name:'',geohash:''}] as data UNWIND data as d MATCH (c:C) WHERE c.name = d.name CREATE (g: G{name :d.geohash} )<-[:cToG]-(c) RETURN c,g`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

After lots of trial and error: sharing the code that finally worked:

```
 Driver driver;
void batchInsert() {
    try (var session = driver.session()) {
        //Create a list of objects
        List<Map<String, Object>> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            Map<String, Object> person = new HashMap<>();
            person.put("id", i);
            person.put("name", UUID.randomUUID()
                    .toString()
                    .substring(0, 10));
            person.put("age", new Random().nextInt(100));
            listOfObjects.add(person);
        }
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("props", listOfObjects);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        session.writeTransaction((tx -> tx.run("UNWIND $props AS map CREATE (n:PERSONS) SET n=map", params).consume()));
        System.out.println("Time Taken to process and save 10000 records to Neo4j Batch Insert took "+ (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");
    }
}
```